# Best method to deploy a node.js web sever as a static site for a portfolio project

Tags: node.js, localhost, webserver

Hi I have a couple I projects that are using the locolhost:3000 sever I want to post them on my portfolio but I'm not sure what would be the best way

this is my package.json

{
  "name": "HyperApp-Starter-kit",

"version": "4.0.1",

"description": "",

"main": "index.js",

"scripts": {

```
"test": "jest",

"build": "gulp build",

"dev:webpack": "webpack --mode development --env.NODE_ENV=dev",

"build:webpack": "webpack --mode production --env.NODE_ENV=production",

"watch": "gulp",

"proxy": "gulp watch-proxy",

"static:dev": "gulp static-dev",

"static:build": "gulp static-dev",

"imgs": "gulp imagemin"
```

},
  "author": "",

"license": "ISC",

"devDependencies": {

```
"@babel/core": "^7.1.5",

"@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.1.0",

"@babel/preset-env": "^7.1.5",

"@babel/preset-es2016": "^7.0.0-beta.53",

"@babel/preset-react": "^7.0.0",

"@babel/preset-stage-0": "^7.0.0",

"@babel/register": "^7.0.0",

"autoprefixer": "^9.3.1",

"axios": "^0.18.0",

"babel-core": "^6.26.3",

"babel-loader": "^8.0.4",

"babel-preset-env": "^1.7.0",

"browser-sync": "^2.26.3",

"clean-webpack-plugin": "^0.1.19",

"css-loader": "^1.0.1",

"extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^4.0.0-beta.0",

"gulp": "^4.0.0",

"gulp-autoprefixer": "^3.1.1",

"gulp-edgejs": "^0.2.4",

"gulp-imagemin": "^5.0.3",

"gulp-pretty-url": "^0.1.1",

"gulp-sass": "^3.0.0",

"har-validator": "^5.1.3",

"html-webpack-plugin": "^3.2.0",

"jest": "^24.8.0",

"mini-css-extract-plugin": "^0.4.4",

"node-sass": "^4.10.0",

"postcss-loader": "^3.0.0",

"prettier": "^1.15.1",

"prettier-loader": "^2.1.1",

"react": "^16.8.6",

"react-dom": "^16.8.6",

"react-redux": "^5.1.0",

"sass-loader": "^7.1.0",

"style-loader": "^0.23.1",


"uglify-es": "^3.3.9",

"uglifyjs-webpack-plugin": "^1.3.0",

"webpack": "^4.25.1",

"webpack-cli": "^3.1.2",

"webpack-md5-hash": "0.0.6"
```

},

"dependencies": {

```
"@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators": "^7.1.6",

"@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import": "^7.0.0",

"@babel/plugin-transform-async-to-generator": "^7.1.0",

"babel-plugin-transform-react-jsx": "^6.24.1",

"gulp-pug": "^4.0.1",

"hyperapp": "^0.12.0",

"svelte": "^3.4.3",

"svelte-loader": "^2.13.4",

"webpack-dev-server": "^3.1.14"
```

}
}

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend Heroku as a great free option for hosting Node.js apps. You can then add links to your apps on your portfolio to share with your visitors.

You can read their [getting started guide](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-nodejs) for node.js to see how you can create a free project.

You can even add a [custom domain](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/custom-domains) for a professional look.

After installing the [Heroku CLI](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-nodejs#set-up) you can run `heroku login` to link your account.

You can then run these commands from within your project folder to get the app live on Heroku.

```
heroku create
git push heroku master
heroku open
```

EDIT: make sure you tell your server to listen to `process.env.PORT || 3000` which will make it obey the port Heroku is setting it to run on.